# Name: Tags: Where: image frozen on my MacBook Air desktop

Tags: performance, icon, desktop, screen-capture

I took a screen shot using <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd> and apparently tapped "Record Selected Section".  That screen shot icon is frozen on my desktop.

I have tried opening Terminal and typing:

```
Killall finder
```

Didn't work.

Then I did a similar command:

```
Killall Docks
```

That didn't work too.

I can't trash it. It's frozen.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's been about 1/2 hour since I did the above actions to clear the frozen icon.  I just opened my Mac and the image is gone!!!

Comment: Nice! Sometimes making a hot beverage, waiting and then restarting things is the fix you need.